# django - refresh JSON data in the template with intervalled AJAX calls

Tags: jquery, python, json, ajax, django

I've checked this [stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/884339/5658350) , but this [snippet](https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/942/) doesn't work for me. I've got an error: 'Template' object has no attribute 'nodelist'.
My data is not displayed in template. My goal is to refresh the data of an already rendered page, so updating a single block from a template.
My code is as follow:

**views.py:**

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        my_data = MyObject.objects.all()
        ctx = { 'test': my_data.values()}
        return render(request, "temp.html", context=ctx)
```

I can see my JSON data in Chrome console after submitting AJAX request , but this data is not displayed in the template.

**my template:**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    {% for v in test %}
        {{ v.path }}
    {% endfor %}
    <script>
    window.setInterval(function(){
      $(document).ready(function() {
              $.ajax({
                  async: true,
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "/requests/",
              });
    });
    }, 2000);
    </script>
```

I see v.path data in Chrome console.

**my json data has the following structure:**

```js
   [ 
     {  
          "pk":4233,
          "model":"hello.webrequest",
          "fields":{  
             "method":"GET",
             "meta":"",
             "user":null,
             "is_secure":false,
             "raw_post":"",
             "user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36",
             "host":"127.0.0.1:8765",
             "path":"/requests/",
             "cookies":"{\"sessionid\": \"1t0ect4zsnfdh5ght7kqhmf3soezueg1\", \"csrftoken\": \"yLImX79fUFJD7kpGQCcfBZawwFtOUcFR\"}",
             "remote_addr_fwd":null,
             "status_code":200,
             "time":"2015-12-17T15:38:04.242Z",
             "post":null,
             "remote_addr":"127.0.0.1",
             "get":null,
             "uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8765/requests/",
             "is_ajax":false
          }
      } 
   ]
```

Also, I've tried HttpResponse, but It doesn't work for me too

Could you please provide some 100% working example?

In this topic [Render JSON objects through Django template-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774100/render-json-objects-through-django-template-tag) i've found such advice:

> if the json comes from your own application, you could return an html
>   fragment instead of json.

But I don't quite understand how can I do this.

UPDATE: i've solved my problem. I refused to use django template tag. Instead of this, I just pass JSON into jQuery script and generate required html.

Comment: can you share the `a` data, to see how it looks like and if there any error message displayed?

Comment: add JSON to my question

Comment: `{% for v in test %}` works only when you have list but your data is not list that'ts why it's not working, it should be as follow [{...},{...}]

Comment: sorry, that JSON is just part of list, update question again

Comment: There is a lot that is *very* bizarre here. Why do you serialize to JSON in your view and then in the next line load it back to Python? What's the point? And if you have an error you should post the whole thing.

Comment: I don't get any error, JSON data just doesn't appear on my page. You see, I've fixed view, but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

User `render` it's less complicated, with `render_to_response` you will not have access to other important variables from other Middlewares, most importantly: user, csrf_token, and messages. To make “render_to_response” pass all these parameters you have to add a “context_instance”.

```js
def my_view(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        my_data = MyObject.objects.all()
        ctx = { 'test': my_data.values()}
        return render(request, "temp.html", context=ctx)
```

and make a whole template if you are not extending a base one:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    window.setInterval(function(){
      $(document).ready(function() {
              $.ajax({
                  async: true,
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "/requests/",
              });
    });
    }, 2000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
 {% for v in test %}
        <li>{{ v.fields.path }}</li>
 {% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've got the same result with render. Add jQuery to my question, maybe there is some problem with script

Comment: Same result, my_data.values() just slightly changes format of JSON. In Chrome console I see value of this variable {{ v.some_field }}, but page remains empty

Comment: Can you share the whole template?

Comment: Why do you use `async: true` and `setInterval`? What's your purpose?

Comment: I want to get some data from my api every n seconds and show it on my page